# Como extraer numero de un String de DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Lo que quiero es tomar el valor numérico de un string por ejemplo
IMP_5 , tomar solo el 5  eso seria en la ultima fila de un DataGridView.
La ultima fila de  registros de todos los que tenga.

Alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: y que intentaste hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto lo podría realizar utilizando una expresión regular.

Ejemplo:

```
        using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
        string soloNumeros = Regex.Match("IMP_5", @"\d+").Value;
        int numero = Convert.ToInt32(soloNumeros);
```

Comment: Gracias!! me sirvio

Comment: @fredmar Si te ha servido la respuesta de Eduardo no olvides darle la respuesta como correcta, esto motiva a la gente a seguir ayudando, un saludo.